# python build error PyUnicodeUCS4

Tags: python, unicode, scikit-learn, nosetests

I have a file on github that works on one of my pc.

you can download it with `git clone -b my-feature https://github.com/DonBeo/scikit-learn.git`

when I run `make` on another pc I get this error:

```
ImportError: /home/donbeo/Documents/scikit-learn/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /home/donbeo/Documents/scikit-learn/sklearn/__check_build:
_check_build.c            setup.py                  __init__.py
_check_build.pyx          __pycache__               setup.pyc
_check_build.so
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.
```

How can I solve that? 
My understanding is that it is a common error in python but that should be solved with a rebuild. How can I rebuild the library keeping it local?

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments my error may be due to the various python versions

```
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ which nosetests
/usr/local/bin/nosetests
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ $ head -1 $(which nosetests)
$: command not found
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ head -1 $(which nosetests)
#!/usr/bin/python3
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$
```

How can I solve?

Comment: How did you build your project on that other PC? The UCS width (UCS2 or UCS4) is taken from the Python configuration files when building, and if you used `make` to build your project and importing then fails, you managed to build with the wrong Python configuration, apparently.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the website in the section how to contribute http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/index.html and then I used make in the terminal

Comment: I see a [closed issue that talks about your error](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2992); where `nosetests` is taken from the wrong Python version.